# React_Display Image from server side into Client

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a code that allows me to send files to server `folder uploads`  using `multer` from `react client side` the process of sending data to server works perfectly and also getting back the file from server works perfectly.

The client side is running under `3000` and the server is running under `4000` .

the problem that I'm facing right now is displaying the file on the front part for ex an `img`

```
 <img
            src={`http:\\localhost:4000\\server\\${text}`}
            className="messageText colorWhite"
            alt="img"
          />
```

the image of the error is below

[image]

the `text` contains `uploads/image1.jpg`

when I inspect the content I found this
[image]

which mean that the image is well called from server side

Could it be possible to help me on this?

Best Regards,

Comment: "http:/..." isnt a valid URL. should be: "http://..." Also URLs should have '/' not '\' slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload folder which contains the files is not being served up by the server at localhost:4000.
You must server the files in the uploads folder first. For eg in an express server you can access the files by specifying this route

```
app.get('/uploads/:filename', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(req.params.filename, {root: path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')});
})
```

Now setting src=http://localhost:4000\uploads\img.png would get the image img.png stored in the uploads folder

Comment: As per your solution if I copy the  url from the `<img src=url` in browser  => it is getting the file from server side but when I refresh the page without  touching the element `img` i get the same result  nothing is showing

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get you

Comment: I tested ur solution => When I write into browser `localhost:4000\uploads\img.jpg` it works and it get the image as I wanted from server but the problem That inside that component `<img>` the result is the same nothing is shown

Comment: I accepted this answer and I will carry on with my search I think there is something with the front

Comment: I think there's a typo after http, ive corrected it, that should work. http:// is the right way and not http\

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can server up the entire uploads folder by

```
app.use(express.static("uploads"));
```

Make sure you specify the full path in "uploads"

Comment: I also tested it `app.use(express.static("./uploads"));` but same thing nothing is shown  https://ibb.co/C0B78wv

Comment: did u understand what I'm trying to say